# How to quickly assign a python dict chain?

Tags: python

Suppose I want to assign:

```
my_dict={}
my_dict['a'] = {}
my_dict['a']['b'] = {}
my_dict['a']['b']['c'] = 'd'
```

Is there a quick way to do this? something like `my_dict['a']['b']['c']='d'`?

Answer (score 1):

You do this with a recursive defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def tree():
    def the_tree():
        return defaultdict(the_tree)
    return the_tree()
```

It is important to wrap the tree in a closure ("private" local function scope).  This prevents existing instances from breaking if the `tree` name is rebound or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
mydict = {'a':{'b':{'c':'d'}}}
```

Comment: for adding the tree to an existing dict, one can use `my_dict.update({'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}})`.